# How to handle foreign characters in a json XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, character-encoding, lotus-domino

I'm trying to understand how I should handle special/foreign characters in a AJAX request.

My test code looks like this:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","test.json",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json; charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send('{"test1":"æøå"}');
```

On the server (IBM Domino) I receive this content REQUEST_CONTENT="{"test1":"├ª├©├Ñ"}". But how do I decode the strange characters?

One solution could be to encodeURIComponent() the value before sending the request. Is this the right way to do it? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @Hariharan — The [send method](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send()-method) doesn't accept a plain object.

Comment: "One solution could be to encodeURIComponent() the value before sending the request." — Could it? Have you tried it? Does it work? If so, then you should be asking about that on codereview and not on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Quentin I'm sending a string not a plain object

Comment: — Yes, but Hariharan recommended sending an object, which is why the comment was addressed to him.

Comment: @Quentin I don't see why this question doesn't belong on stackoverflow. I have a specific programming problem. And I'm asking for alternative solutions?!?

Comment: If you've got a solution, then you're asking people to critique the solution not solve a problem (since you've already solved it).

Comment: Ok, the @Hariharan entry must have been deleted, before I could read it

Answer (score 0):

I take it that is a Web Agent you are calling? If so, then what you are getting back is what is expected in the agent.

REQUEST_CONTENT is not translated when read. So what you are seeing is raw UTF-8 in the string. You would need to decode that manually.

The safest way is to URLEncode before sending and URLDecode the data to maintain the characters.

The other option is to use the JSON services components in XPages

[Extlib OpenNTF](http://extlib.openntf.org) has a sample database for extlib JSON services. [Here is that DB hosted](http://domino8.strandplatsen.se/openntf/xpagesext.nsf/REST_DataService.xsp) (not sure who is hosting it, so no guarantee it will stay there).

Another option is the [Domino Data Service](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino%20Data%20Service#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=api) (DDS). This allows you to access views/documents as JSON format directly.

Of the three options, personally I'd go with the XPages solution as it allows better control over the data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Options one, urlencode/urldecode is definitely a possibility, all though it's bit of a pain to remember to encode everything. Option two, xPages, I haven't used xPages before so it will probably require too much work. But what you are saying is, that it's possible to make a json request to a xPage, decode the content and have it return a json response?

Comment: Yes. Not the XPage directly, but the JSON component.

Answer (score 0):

What language is your agent written in?  In Java it you could use getBytes to convert the REQUEST_CONTENT data into a byte array, and then just instantiate it into a new UTF-8 string.  Something along these lines:

```
byte[] requestContentBytes = requestContentString.getBytes();
String reqeustContentUTF8 = new new new String(requestContentBytes,"UTF-8");
```

Actually, I'm not sure about the getBytes() call.  You may need to provide a charset argument to that.  With no argument, it should use the platform default charset to translate the String value to bytes.  If the OS the agent is running on has the same default charset as the one you are viewing the string on, then I think that's the right way.  If you do need a charset argument, though, the point is it won't be UTF-8 -- otherwise the net effect when feeding into new String with the UTF-8 argument would be a no-op.

Comment: To clarify why I think the no argument form will be correct if the OS platform default charset is the same as your client charset: it's because I presume that the string you pasted above ("├ª├©├Ñ"}") was copied from your client, and it looks to me like it's probably a valid UTF-8 stream rendered as single-byte characters.

Comment: My agent is written in LotusScript, but I can switch to Java if required. Getting content as a byte and the converting it to at utf-8 string might also be possible in LotusScript. I'll give it a try and return with some feedback later. Thanks

Comment: This is not working for me. Doing like this: byte[] content = "├ª├©├Ñ".getBytes(); String ss = new String(content, "UTF-8"); will just print a question mark. It might be that my Eclipse is messing things up, but I also tried some online compilers without luck.

Comment: UTF-8 is not likely to be directly displayable on your machine, so if what you're saying is that you can't see the correct characters in Eclipse, I think that's to be expected.  (I can't think of any OS that has UTF-8 as it's native charset, but perhaps Eclipse has a setting to translate UTF-8 to native.  I don't know.)  But have you tried sending the data in your XmlHttpRequest?  You're setting UTF-8 in your content-type header, so the system that receives that POST ought to deal with it.  Second question: what are the hex values that you are seeing in the byte array?